# Writing specific cells in Excel to a CSV using For Loops in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to write cells E3:E16 of a specific sheet to a CSV (or TXT for that matter) upon opening of the excel document.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Open "W:\Folder\Folder\Folder\locations.csv" For Output As #1
    For cCount = 3 To 16
        Print #1, Range("E" + cCount)
    Next cCount
Close #1
End Sub
```

I am getting Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch.

Is a For loop the way to go in VBA? This is my first time ever using it and am used to python and Java.

Comment: `+` should be `&`.

Comment: To make sure that the range is from the specific sheet that you want, I suggest adding the Parent Objects to the statement like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Range(...` Or you can use the VB Project "Codename" of the sheet like `Sheet1.Range(...`